# Experience using IRC to coordinate software development?

Tags: irc

I am part of a growing software project with at least 200 active developer in 10 locations.  I would like to set up an on-line chat forum for developers because I think it would help to coordinate efforts.  We have an email mailing list but I feel like some questions or announcements are too informal to send to everyone while mentioning it in a chat forum might be a useful community resource.

I have never participated in a software project that used an on-line chat forum so I would like to hear about peoples experiences.  I am particularly interested in technical issues: Use of IRC vs. alternative platforms; how to manage access, eg. for developers only, allowing users to participate; the value of requiring certain announcements to be made on the chat forum eg who is resolving broken builds etc.

If I pitch the idea to the community I would like to have some good arguments why it would be a good idea and some prospective of its usefulness in other software projects.

Comment: Do you need to talk to all 200 developers? Aren't there any sub-team leads?

Comment: We use Openfire http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/ with the Spark chat client. Messages can be archived and searched, though I don't like the search interface much. That said, it has been an invaluable tool for us. Group conversations can be set up either permenantly or ad-hoc, also the ability to easily send screenshots and files to other users is a useful bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The features you MOST want for such informal discussions are:

- persistance (I have't used IRC in >decade, does it persist chats that you missed?)
- Searcheability
- Classification (tagging) to help sort through the stuff.

Considering those 3, I'd strongly suggest some sort of discussion software (microblog, Wiki, forum) with RSS feed.

Comment: +1 for persistence: *every* decision, no matter how "minor", should be documented somewhere. Particularly with such a large team.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great platform for informal discussions. It's flexible, users can self-organize and its extensible. We have tied CI build results and SCM commits. Further, given the availability of multiple consumption streams (web, terminal) anyone can join with little notice.

I think the previous poster is over-stating the importance of the contents of this conversation and who the heck wants to maintain discussion software? Blergh.